# Retrieving and displaying photo with phonegap works in emulator but not on my phone

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am using the PhonGap API to take a photo and display it in the app. It all works fine in the emulator (using Ripple extension in chrome) but doesn't work on my phone or tablet (both android). Anyone got any ideas why?

EDIT: I've now established that it is taking and returning the photo ok, and it is creating the canvas, it is just not drawing the image to the canvas for some reason.

Edit 2: now resolved after reading this: [How can I load an image onto the HTML5 Canvas using Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124892/how-can-i-load-an-image-onto-the-html5-canvas-using-phonegap). Later features not working . . . but in my case it looks like the problem wasn't permissions.

```
// Called by 'Take Photo' button
function takePhoto() {
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string. If      
  //camera unavailable it will offer the option to retrieve a file
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL } );
}


// Displays the image on the screen   
function onSuccess (imageData) {   

alert("Hello " + imageData.length); //added this to check if anything was making it to     
///this point

    var image = document.getElementById("image");
    image.src = imageData;
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");        
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,c.width,c.height);        
}


function onFail(message) {
  alert("Failed because: " + message);
}
```

Comment: which one phonegap version you can use ?

Comment: The emulator is 2.0 and that's what I've been using in my program as well unless there was an intermediary between 2.0 and 3.0

Answer (score 0):

```
    Paste this on Andorid confing.xml

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/contacts"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>

    Paste this on AndroidManifest.xml 

    uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
    <activity  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```